# Running an .exe file while also taking in parameters from a java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

How do you take in multiple parameters specified in a GUI to run in an external .exe file (GLPK solver)?

Is this possible?

Comment: Which bit are you having problems with - getting the input, or starting a new process with arguments?

Comment: we are having issues on getting the parameters to run in GLPK

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/glpk-4.47/w64/glpsol.exe","-m NetFlow2stage.mod -o NetFlow2stageJAVA.sol -d NetworkData2.dat").start();
        
     
        System.out.println("...");
        
        String content = "out!";

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String func)` function. You can execute the external program as well as pass arguments to it.

For example:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe JavaProgram.java")` will execute `notepad.exe` while also opening the file `JavaProgram.java`, creating the file if it doesn't exist(when you save it)

Answer (score 0):

Your main method:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
```

contains everything you need to get the parmeters as they will be assigned to the `args` array.

If or do you need to use java to execute the exe? That can be done by using this:

```
String[] cmd = { "myProgram.exe", "-o=This is an option" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

**EDIT**
Try this as the path:

> C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\glpk-4.47\\w64\\glpsol.exe

Comment: it is not able to run the executable file when we tried that.

Comment: it throws an IOException saying cannot run program "glpsol.exe": CreateProcess error=2

Comment: What is the absolute path of the executable?

Comment: I changed the file to be the right folder.  The code compiles and runs with no errors however the executable file is still not running... :/ I am not sure why it isn't running

Comment: Open up command prompt, and try and start your executable from there with your passed parameters. Do you get any errors? Does it run? The above code I have used and it has worked with various executables.

Comment: Yeah, I run it from the command prompt and it works fine.  But when I run it thru Java, it isn't working...

String[] cmd = { "C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\glpk-4.47\\w64\\glpsol.exe" , "-m NetFlow2stage.mod" , "-o NetFlow2stageJAVA.sol" , " -d NetworkData2.dat"};
       
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: Try just this: `String[] cmd = { "C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\glpk-4.47\\w64\\glpsol.exe" , "-m NetFlow2stage.mod -o NetFlow2stageJAVA.sol -d NetworkData2.dat"};` The executable is the first part of the array, and then all parameters get passed as the second part.

Comment: Still nothing :/ I know glpsol works with those parameters because I have been running it from the command line.  Just can't seem to get it to run from Java (which I need to interact with my GUI)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/glpk-4.47/w64/glpsol.exe","-m NetFlow2stage.mod -o NetFlow2stageJAVA.sol -d NetworkData2.dat").start(); 
System.out.println("..."); 
String content = "out!";
```

is almost correct - almost. The arguments should be separate parameters for the ProcessBuilder constructor. Try this:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/glpk-4.47/w64/glpsol.exe","-m NetFlow2stage.mod", "-o NetFlow2stageJAVA.sol", "-d NetworkData2.dat").start(); 
System.out.println("..."); 
String content = "out!";
```